# What could be meaning and translation of the word "vivid" in this context: "Vividness is self-selecting"

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, значения, выражения

There are following lines in a poem:
"Observe what’s vivid"
and
"Vividness is self-selecting"

Word "vivid" is usually translated as "яркий", "ясный". What could be meaning of "vividness" in this context?

Comment: You hadn't provided much of a context. Also, it's a poetry that makes things even more complicated.

Comment: Those are self-contained sentences. If this can help: "Ordinary mind includes eternal perceptions. / Observe what’s vivid. / Notice what you notice. / Catch yourself thinking. / Vividness is self-selecting. / If we don’t show anyone, we’re free to write anything."

Comment: That's Allen Ginsberg poetry and it is definitely _cannot_ be translated just one way. As the poet said, just "observe what’s vivid". I vote to close this question as seeking for translation, showing no research effort, and having little to do with the Russian language. You'd better go to the [English Language & Usage SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) and ask them to explain what it means, that will help you much better than a closed question here.